# How to display codeigniter table in view from controller using ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

```
  <div class="panel-body">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '<?php echo site_url('welcome/displayallquestionsandoptions')?>',
    data : '' // query string
    success : function(formagain){
        $('.panel-body').html(formagain);
        //this will replace the content of div with new form
    } 
});


        </script>


    </div>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
 public function displayallquestionsandoptions() {


     if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
       $this->load->database();


    $this->load->library('table');

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT QuestionId,Name,SurveyId,CreatedOn from question");

    $table = $this->table->generate($query); 



}else{

}

}
```

Please help i am new to codeigniter and php

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you need to `echo` the table generated by `$this->table->generate($query);` back to your ajax call.  Also you need to pass  an array or a database result object to the `generate` function.  So you need to add/amend the following lines in your controller

```
$table = $this->table->generate($query->result_array()); //Pass an array
echo $table; //Added this
```

Your success function in your AJAX call will then capture the data echoed back from the controller and you can do what you want with it.

```
success : function(formagain){ //foragain contains the table HTML from the controller
    $('.panel-body').html(formagain);
    //this will replace the content of div with new form
}
```

Comment: I am still not able to get the data